# Get summary from main activity

Tags: android, preferences

I create a SwitchPreference by code in a PreferenceActivity class:

```
SwitchPreference l_Server = new SwitchPreference(this);
l_Server.setKey("Server" + l_Number);
l_Server.setTitle("Server number " + l_Number);
l_Server.setSummary("summary of a server");
```

I can get its Boolean value by using SharedPreference. However, how can I get its summary and title from the MainActivity?

Comment: What you want to say is how to get title,summary into main activiy?

Comment: In  MainActivity class, I want to get title and summary of SwitchPreference which was created dynamically in PreferenceActivity.

Comment: when you do setTitle, also store it into shared preferences!